# How to deploy android plugin that can be loaded from my application

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm writing an application that can load third party plugins that are executable code that provide a contract.  Is this possible?

For example if I want to add support for a particular decoder is it possible to just update the decoder rather than updating the entire application?

Answer (score 0):

what u need is Dynamic Class Loading and Reloading in Java using Java Reflection.
you can find many online tutorials regarding this.